# If two events co-occur, then is their probability equal?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

If two events co-occur, then is their probability equal?

I’m trying to figer out why it is true that if $X_n$ converges to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges to $Y$, then since addition is continuous, $X_n + Y_n$ converges to $X+Y$.

In doing so, I thought it makes sense that since addition maps one-to-one (i.e. is continuous), then 
$P[X_n+Y_n $converge to $ X+Y]=P[(X_n$ converges to $X ) \cap (Y_n $converges to $Y)] =1 $.

But I am seein in resources such as this one http://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/vidsand12.pdf on page 10, lemma 1.2.10 that one is less than or equal to the other?

$P[X_n+Y_n $converge to $X+Y]\ge P[(X_n$ converges to $X ) \cap (Y_n $converges to $Y)] =1 $ .

Why aren’t these two probabilities always equal?

Comment: You take the product of the probabilities while in the resource they are speaking about the intersection of two events. You don't know whether these two events are independent. Do you see that?

Comment: What is the meaning of $P(A)\cap P(B)$?

Comment: Te title also makes no sense.

Comment: I agree actually te title makes no sense.  I'm having trouble phrasing it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the author probably meant by addition is continuous is that the function $(x, y) \mapsto x+y$ is continuous. That let us conclude the convergence of the sum of two convergent random variables.

Indeed, for any $\omega$ such that $X_n(\omega) $ and $Y_n(\omega) $ converges it holds that $X_n(\omega) +Y_n(\omega) $ converges. The converse does not have to be true. Indeed take a divergent $X_n(\omega) $ and set $Y_n=-X_n$, then the sum converges but the individual random variables do not.

That means
$$\{X_n \text{ converges to } X \} \cap \{Y_n \text{ converges to } Y \}\subset \{X_n +Y_n\text{ converges to } X+Y \}$$
The inequality is then a consequence of the subadditivity of the probability measure. Moreover the intersection of two events with probability one has probability one as well. Just look at the complement and see that it is a null set.

Comment: What does the resource that I cited mean when it says "as addition is continuous"?  This statement confuses me since addition is a binary operator, not a function.

Comment: @jaja oh I see it, they probably mean that the function $f(x, y) =x+y$ is continuous. From there you can indeed conclude that $X_n+Y_n$ converges if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converges. Is it clear?

Comment: Well, I see that part about "addition is continuous" thank you @Sashi.  But I do not understand the following:  When you say “for any $\omega$ such that $X_n(\omega) $ and $Y_n(\omega) $ converges it holds that $X_n(\omega) +Y_n(\omega) $ converges” then that makes me think that the set containment should actually go the other way:  $$\{X_n +Y_n\text{ converges to } X+Y \}\subset \{X_n \text{ converges to } X \} \cap \{Y_n \text{ converges to } Y \} $$ 
 How does the logic A implies B mean that $B\subset A$?...what am I missing here?

Comment: @jaja when I say that I take $\omega$ such that $X_n(\omega) $ and $Y_n(\omega) $ converges, I actually take $\omega\in\{X_n \text{ converges } \} \cap\{ Y_n \text{ converges} \} $ and show that $\omega \in\{ X_n+Y_n$ converges $\} $. What does that show? The inclusion mentioned in the post, right?

Comment: I'm sorry but intuitively it still seems backwards to me.  you're still saying that $\omega \in {X_n converges} \cap {Y_n converges} \rightarrow \omega \in {X_n + Y_n converges } $, right ?  So to me that seems like a logical statement A implies B....but then the inclusion you have written in your post would mean that event B includes event A? sorry for not understanding.

Comment: @jaja if you shwo that every $a$ in some set $A$ is also in set $B$ then is not that the same as saying $A\subset B$? That's what I am claiming.

Comment: oh i see.  sorry for being so dense I get it now. thanks so mcuh.

Comment: @jaja it's good as long as you understand it.